# Automator - Shell Script - ffmpeg: image sequence to video

Tags: terminal, automator, video

Terminal can generate video from PNG seguence (0001.png, 0002.png, ...) via ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i %04d.png -r 24 -codec prores output.mov
```

But how can I tell ffmpeg use for input image sequence in Automator? With this variable it's not working:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    /opt/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "$f" -r 24 -codec prores ~/Desktop/output.mov
done
```

Looks like variable is for file than for sequence ... Log list looks like script runs 10 times for sequence of 10 images. Error probably comes from second and all others loops where is asking for overwriting existing. I was able to create video only with full path to image sequence like `~/Desktop/PNG_Folder/%04d.png`, but thats not solution. Script was asking 9 times for overwriting anyway (skipping error with `-y` hides error but keep loop process) and I need of course to use files selected from Finder, not specified in full path written in a script :) Here is a screen of Automator just to be sure other things are set right. Thank you for help.

[image]

Plus: original Terminal command lets generate video into image sequence directory. Is this possible also with Automator's Shell? Also variable would be better if can be set for any file name and more formats than PNG (JPEG, EXR, ...?) t be more versatile. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing a bit of research, it turns out that the `-i` *option* for `ffmpeg` takes a single *filename* and when converting a number of *image files* to a *.mov file*, it has to be in the form of e.g. `%05d.png`. Obviously the padding of the *sequential numbering* can be a different number of digits and the *image type extension* can vary as well.

Then to that end, the following *example* `bash` *code* works for me:

**Method 1:**

The following assumes the *sequential numbered files* are *four digits*, starting at `0001`, add all *files* have the same *extension*.

It will process all *four digit sequential numbered files* in the same *directory* while overwriting the `output.mov` *file*, if it already exists.

Change **Service receives selected** `files or folders` **in**`Finder` to:

**Service receives selected** `folders` **in** `Finder`

Remove the **Get Selected Finder Items** *action*,

Set **Pass input:** to `as arguments` in the **Run Shell Script** *action*.

Replace the default *code* with the following *example* `bash` *code*:

```
cd "$1" || exit
ext="$(file="$(ls 0001.*)"; echo "${file##*.}")"
/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg -y -i %04d.${ext} -r 24 -codec prores output.mov
```

The *example* `bash` *code* above assumes you are selecting only one *folder* in **Finder**.  For multiple *folder* selections, use the following *example* `bash` *code*:

```
for f in "$@"; do
    cd "$f" || exit
    ext="$(file="$(ls 0001.*)"; echo "${file##*.}")"
    /opt/local/bin/ffmpeg -y -i %04d.${ext} -r 24 -codec prores output.mov
done
```

<sub>**Note:** The *example* `bash` *code* contains limited *error handling*. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted.</sub>

---

**Method 2:**

**Service receives selected** `files or folders` **in** `Finder`

Remove the **Get Selected Finder Items** *action*,

Set **Pass input:** to `as arguments` in the **Run Shell Script** *action*.

Assuming the selected *image files* in **Finder** are all the same type, in the same *folder* and the e.g. `output.mov` *file* will be created in the same *folder* of the selected *image files*...

Then to that end, the following *example* `bash` *code* works for me:

```
o="output"
e="mov"

d="$(dirname "$1")"
cd "$d" || exit

if [[ ! -e "${o}.${e}" ]]; then
    o="${o}.${e}"
else
    n=2
    for f in ${o} *.${e}; do
        if [[ "${o} ${n}.${e}" == "$f" ]]; then
            n="$(( n + 1 ))"
        fi
    done
    o="${o} ${n}.${e}"
fi

foo="$(date +%s)"
mkdir "/tmp/${foo}" || exit
cd "/tmp/${foo}" || exit

i=1
for f in "$@"; do
    ln -s "$f" "$(printf "%05d" $i).${f##*.}"
    (( i++ ))
done

/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg -i %05d."${f##*.}" -r 24 -codec prores "${d}/${o}"

rm -r "/tmp/${foo}"
```

<sub>**Note:** The *example* `bash` *code* contains limited *error handling*. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted.</sub>

**Method 2 Notes:**

- If the e.g. `output.mov` *file* already exists, an incremented *filename* is used, starting at, e.g. `output 2.mov` and continuing to increment as needed so the **Automator** *Service* doesn't fail because the *output file* already exists. This is primarily handled in the `if...else...then` *block*; however, the lines of *code* prior to it are a part of it as well.
- In order to accomplish the goal, a temporary *directory* is created in `/tmp`, named for the number of seconds since the *Unix epoch*, e.g. `/tmp/1574058046` and is handle by `foo="$(date +%s)"` and `mkdir "/tmp/${foo}"`.
- Within this temporary *directory* a *sequential numbered symlink* is created for each of the selected *image files*, and is handled primarily by the `for f in "$@"; do ... done` *loop*.
- `ffmpeg` then creates the e.g. `output.mov` *file*.
- The temporary *directory*, e.g, `/tmp/1574058046` is removed.
- Note that the selected *image files* must all be of the same *type* per run, however, each run can use a different supported *image file type* as long as all are the same *type* per run. As currently coded you can not mix different *image file types* per each run of the *service*.

---

**Note:** The **Get Specified Finder Items** *action* is just for testing purposes and would be deleted before saving the **Automator** *Service*.

[image]

Comment: I'm surprised one can't do this: **`cd "$(dirname "$1")"; for f in "$@"; do input="$input -i \"$f\""; done; eval "ffmpeg$input -r 24 -codec prores output.mov"`**.  I thought `ffmpeg` could accept multiple input files by using the `-i` flag in multiple.

Comment: @vklidu, Doesn't matter the naming convention of the source image files. The _script_ is coded to take the selected items in Finder and create a .mov file from them. So e.g. `Screen Shot 2019-11-18 at 2.01.33 AM.png` becomes `00001.png` _sysmlink_ and `Screen Shot 2019-11-18 at 2.02.00 AM.png` becomes `00002.png` _sysmlink_ **or** `0001.png` becomes `00001.png` _sysmlink_ and `0002.png` becomes `00002.png` _sysmlink_, etc. This is code this way to handle both scenarios as well as allowing for passing all selected files to `ffmpeg` using `-i %05d."${f##*.}"` As you see @CJK's code doesn't work.

Comment: I'd like to point out I made no assertion as to the effectiveness of, what was after all, a query.  I _thought_ (from some vague past memory) that it _might_ have been possible, and wanted to check with @user3439894, who is by far the more experienced shell scripter.  Had I felt with any confidence that mine would be the way to go, I would have offered it as a second answer.  Anyway, +1 to this solution, which must have been a mare to conceive, write and test.

Comment: @CJK, After you posted the original comment I tested it and while it did create a .mov file I did not play it and just assumed it worked. I have to admin I was socked it worked (I thought) because the research I did didn't show that `-i` could be used more than once and it only took one file, with the exception of using the e.g. `-i %04d.png` form to use a set of sequentially numbered files. I certainly didn't mean the comment I made about your code to be harsh, was at the character limit so it came off terse, sorry. It actually was very easy to conceive, write and test, but thanks for the +1!